# How to decrypt using Blowfish in Pycrypto?

Tags: python, pycrypto, blowfish

I found one example to encrypt the data but I am unable to find any example on how to decrypt it.

Encryption Example:

```
>>> from Crypto.Cipher import Blowfish
>>> from Crypto import Random
>>> from struct import pack
>>>
>>> bs = Blowfish.block_size
>>> key = b'An arbitrarily long key'
>>> iv = Random.new().read(bs)
>>> cipher = Blowfish.new(key, Blowfish.MODE_CBC, iv)
>>> plaintext = b'docendo discimus '
>>> plen = bs - divmod(len(plaintext),bs)[1]
>>> padding = [plen]*plen
>>> padding = pack('b'*plen, *padding)
>>> msg = iv + cipher.encrypt(plaintext + padding)
```

I did not find any example on how to decrypt.

Comment: I removed your second part of your question, because it is simply too broad. If you can make it clear what it is that you didn't understand, then you can ask either another question here on Stack Overflow if it's code related or if it is really about the inner workings, then you can ask on [crypto.se]. Be aware that a block cipher is rather complicated and it is not good to ask for a complete description of such a cipher on the Stack Exchange network. You should read an introductory book into cryptography that also describes Blowfish.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Let's make some observations:

- CBC mode needs an Initialization Vector (IV) that has the same length as the block size (64bit for Blowfish)
- the full plaintext is the actual message including padding (PKCS#5 padding in [RFC 2898 Sec. 6.1.1 Step 4](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2898#section-6.1.1))
- the IV is prepended to the ciphertext

What needs to be done:

- Use the same key
- Read the IV before creating the decryptor
- Remove padding after decryption by looking at the last byte, evaluate that as an integer and remove as many bytes from the end of the plaintext

Code:

```
from Crypto.Cipher import Blowfish
from struct import pack

bs = Blowfish.block_size
key = b'An arbitrarily long key'
ciphertext = b'\xe2:\x141vp\x05\x92\xd7\xfa\xb5@\xda\x05w.\xaaRG+U+\xc5G\x08\xdf\xf4Xua\x88\x1b'
iv = ciphertext[:bs]
ciphertext = ciphertext[bs:]

cipher = Blowfish.new(key, Blowfish.MODE_CBC, iv)
msg = cipher.decrypt(ciphertext)

last_byte = msg[-1]
msg = msg[:- (last_byte if type(last_byte) is int else ord(last_byte))]
print(repr(msg))
```

Comment: >>> msg = msg[:-ord(msg[-1])]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#57>", line 1, in <module>
    msg = msg[:-ord(msg[-1])]
TypeError: ord() expected string of length 1, but int found

Comment: Yeah, in Python 3 you have to remove `ord`, because `msg[-1]` is already an integer. I've also updated the code so that it works with Python2 and Python 3